# Will upgrading Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 change my files?

Tags: upgrade

I know how silly it will be if I ask this question, please do bear with me as I am new to Ubuntu.

I have my project done in Eclipse in Ubuntu 10.04. As I wanted to add some extra features in my project I could not do it in Eclipse Juno.

My question is if I upgrade my ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 or any other latest version, will my existing project remain the same or will it affect my existing project, which I have in ubuntu 10.04?

If not, can I upgrade it using the update manager?

Comment: You talk about an eclipse project (that sort of not works?) and upgrading to the latest LTS, two completely different things. What problem are you actually trying to solve? If you work on software projects on your own you should learn to use version control systems (VCS) and you should do backups. Because unexpected things happen! That's why you should always have at least another copy of your data somewhere and you will soon learn the benefits of documenting your own code in a VCS for yourself, if you haven't already. A newer version of eclipse should be able to handle old projects.

Comment: I have installed Hadoop in ubuntu 10.04. Will the Hadoop will remain the same while upgrading or Do I need to set up Hadoop once again.

Comment: Kindly help me out with this question. Awaiting  your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your data will not be lost. Go for it. Use the update manager and upgrade.

It will take a little time though.

Comment: I have installed Hadoop also in Ubuntu 10.04. Will It remain while upgrading or Do I need to  set up hadoop once again.

Comment: Kindly help me out with this question.Awaiting your reply.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used that before. I'm originally a EEE major. I've never encountered any sort of data-loss while upgrading. I imagine your server or Apache has configurations, which might be a subject to change. Cause, every time I upgrade, I do have to fiddle with the settings to my comfort.
By no means I'm an expert. So I guess it's better to knock some expert on this.